# VBA: For each wCell in wRange

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I'm having issues with a For Each loop.

I'm trying to use the loop:

```
wRange = Range(Cells(5, countryCol), Cells(lastrow, countryCol))
For Each wCell In wRange
    If wCell = "Unknown" Then
        wCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Follow up with receiving"
        wCell.Offset(0, followUp - countryCol) = "Send to receiving"
    End If
Next
```

When I define variables as:

```
Dim wRange As Range
Dim wCell As Range
```

I get a Run-Time error `Object variable or With block variable not set` on the line

`wRange = Range(Cells(5, countryCol), Cells(lastrow, countryCol))`

When I define variables as:

`Dim wRange, wCell As Range`

I get a Run-Time error: `Object required` on the line

`For Each wCell In wRange`

---

If I use the loop like

```
For Each cell In wRange
    If cell = "Unknown" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Follow up with receiving"
        cell.Offset(0, followUp - countryCol) = "Send to receiving"
    End If
Next
```

I get a Run-Time error `Object required` on the line

`cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Follow up with receiving"`

Comment: Might want to qualify your range.

Comment: You need to use `Set`: `Set wRange = Range(Cells(5, countryCol), Cells(lastrow, countryCol))`

Comment: As said by @Rory, you only need to use the `Set` keyword everytime you are assigning a value to an object variable.

Comment: @Rory I thank you and R3uk.  Small detail I'd forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments to the original question, I need to use a `Set`

```
Set wRange = Range(Cells(5, countryCol), Cells(lastrow, countryCol))
For Each wCell In wRange
    If wCell = "Unknown" Or wCell = "" Then
        wCell.Offset(0, reviewStatus - countryCol).Value = "Follow up with receiving"
        wCell.Offset(0, followUp - countryCol) = "Send to receiving"
    End If
Next
```